# Composer does not recognize the extension php-zip

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a problem with composer while i try to create new project by:

```
laravel new blog
```

After run this command composer says:

```
  [RuntimeException] The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again.
```

I installed php7.1-zip, zip, unzip, php-zip and it's still not working.
My OS is Debian 9 and i have installed php7.1 and php7.1-zip. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

If you see that it does not work, try to restart your machine.

Comment: There is no need to restart the machine. You need to restart the web service (Apache, probably) to let it know about the new extension. There is usually no need to do anything in order to make the extension available to the PHP command line.

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing it. @MaciejGrzesiak

Comment: I tried couple of times to reinstall also full reinstal apache and php.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `info.php` file in your web root containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Then load that file in a browser.

It's possible your Apache isn't configured to use the install of PHP that you're expecting. `phpinfo()` will show you which version of PHP it's loading, where the loaded `php.ini` is located, which extensions are enabled, etc.